# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 0 into shape (224,512) - plotting heat maps to localize anomalies in images

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I've been using VGG16 to create a model that can classify images into two categories, which works perfectly fine. Now I want to create a function to localize anomalies through heat maps as in here: https://towardsdatascience.com/anomaly-detection-in-images-777534980aeb

Unfortunately that's not working for me, the array including my test image has either the wrong size (`ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1, 224, 224, 3)` or `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (224, 224, 3)`) or it's telling me `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 0 into shape (224,512)`. Here you can see a code snippet:

```
[...]
test_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)
test_data_gen = test_image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=batch_size,
                                                         directory=test_dir,
                                                         shuffle=False,
                                                         target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
                                                         class_mode='binary')
# create the model/ import vgg16

vgg_conv = vgg16.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape = (224, 224, 3))

# Freeze the layers except the last 4 layers
for layer in vgg_conv.layers[:-8]:
    layer.trainable = False

# Check the trainable status of the individual layers
for layer in vgg_conv.layers:
    print(layer, layer.trainable)

# modify vgg structure

x = vgg_conv.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(x)

model = Model(vgg_conv.input, x)
model.compile(loss = "binary_crossentropy", optimizer = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.00001, momentum=0.9), metrics=["accuracy"])

model.summary()

[...]

### CREATE FUNCTION TO DRAW ANOMALIES ###

def plot_activation(img):
    pred = model.predict(img[:,:,:,:])
    pred_class = np.argmax(pred)
    weights = model.layers[-1].get_weights()[0]  # weights last classification layer
    class_weights = weights[:, pred_class]

    intermediate = Model(model.input, model.get_layer("block5_conv3").output)
    conv_output = intermediate.predict(img)
    conv_output = np.squeeze(conv_output)

    h = int(img.shape[0] / conv_output.shape[0])
    w = int(img.shape[1] / conv_output.shape[1])

    activation_maps = sp.ndimage.zoom(conv_output, (h, w, 1), order=1)
    out = np.dot(activation_maps.reshape((img.shape[0] * img.shape[1], 512)), class_weights).reshape(img.shape[0],
                                                                                                     img.shape[1])

    plt.imshow(img.astype('float32').reshape(img.shape[0], img.shape[1], 3))
    plt.imshow(out, cmap='jet', alpha=0.35)
    plt.title('Crack' if pred_class == 1 else 'No Crack')

    # return out, pred_class

img_width, img_height = 224, 224
img = image.load_img('/Volumes/test_image.jpg', target_size = (img_width, img_height))
img = image.img_to_array(img)
img = np.expand_dims(img, axis = 0)

plot_activation(img)
```

With that code I'm getting the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 285, in <module>
    plot_activation(img)
  File "test.py", line 251, in plot_activation
    out = np.dot(activation_maps.reshape((img.shape[0] * img.shape[1], 512)), class_weights).reshape(img.shape[0],
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 0 into shape (224,512)
```

I've tried to resize my array but probably haven't done that the right way as I'm only getting different errors (see above). Maybe it's got something to do with how I've been preprocessing the images, but I'm not sure about that one. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?
Additionally -  do I need to undo the preprocessing to plot the heat maps correctly ? If so, how will I be able to do so?

If there are any questions left, feel free to ask, I'm happy to answer.

**EDIT:**
This is my adjusted code which now is working fine:

```
### CREATE FUNCTION TO DRAW ANOMALIES ###

def plot_activation(img):
    pred = model.predict(img[np.newaxis,:,:,:])
    # pred_class = np.argmax(pred)
    pred_class = np.argmax(pred, axis=-1)
    weights = model.layers[-1].get_weights()[0]  # weights last classification layer
    class_weights = weights[:, pred_class]

    intermediate = Model(model.input, model.get_layer("block5_conv3").output)
    conv_output = intermediate.predict(img[np.newaxis,:,:,:])
    conv_output = np.squeeze(conv_output)


    h = int(img.shape[0] / conv_output.shape[0])
    w = int(img.shape[1] / conv_output.shape[1])

    activation_maps = sp.ndimage.zoom(conv_output, (h, w, 1), order=1)
    out = np.dot(activation_maps.reshape((img.shape[0] * img.shape[1], 512)), class_weights).reshape(img.shape[0],
                                                                                                     img.shape[1])

    plt.imshow(img.astype('float32').reshape(img.shape[0], img.shape[1], 3))
    plt.imshow(out, cmap='jet', alpha=0.35)
    plt.title('Crack' if pred_class == 1 else 'No Crack')
    plt.show()

    # return out, pred_class

test_images = test_data_gen[0][0][0]

plot_activation(test_images)
```

Comment: the original code works (I double-check it). the first error is because u don't pass to the model an image of shape (1,224,224,3). you also need to repeat the same preprocess step

Comment: Evidently `activation_maps = sp.ndimage.zoom(conv_output, (h, w, 1), order=1)` has produced a `size 0` array - one without any content. I'd look at `activation_maps.shape` and its `dtype`.  And if needed trace it back through `conv_output` and `img`.

Comment: Apparently I've made several mistakes passing the test image to the function. I've adjusted my code and now it's working fine (see edit). The only problem left is that the heat map has such strong colours that you basically can't see anything left from the actual image which isn't that helpful in actually detecting the anomalies the model has found. How can I change that?